# Jquery Cycle plugin: first image appears floating right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have installed the [JQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html) on my site and it works fine but for the first image which appears floating off to the right when the page loads. This just happens to the first image - all others are ok.

I am not sure why this is occurring as all my code is very simple:

```
$(function() {
  $('#banner').cycle('fade');
});
```

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src="images/banner01.jpg"  />
    <img src="images/banner02.jpg"  />
    <img src="images/banner03.jpg"  />
    <img src="images/banner04.jpg"  />
    <img src="images/banner05.jpg"  />
  </div>
```

```
#banner
{
    width: 750px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 370px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#banner IMG
{
    width: 750px;
    height: 320px;
}
```

I am not sure what I have done wrong or what I can do to fix it. Would anyone know?

The site is here if you want to look: http://austin7.org.au/

EDIT: I have tried moving the JQuery script to the bottom of the page too, to no affect. Also, I have tried using different images - they all have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `left` to `0`.

```
#banner img{
    left: 0;
}
```